# Future of Java on Mac OS X

Tags: java, .net, macos

I'm mainly developing in .NET since a year (even if I start coding in Java during my studies) and I have to port a .NET application (more precisely an agent running as Windows Service which call a web service to transfer information and files) to Mac OS X.

My first idea was to develop a Java version of the application. But I read some articles about the future of Java on Mac OS X and I'm a little perplexed about this choice.

What do you think?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The future of Java on Mac is fine. Apple is contributing their code to the OpenJDK project, which has also started a project (starting Java 7) to build binaries for Mac. So, in the near future, we Mac users will be able to install JREs and JDKs pretty much the same way that Windows and Linux users do.

Have a read [here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/macosx-port/) and [here](http://www.java7developer.com/blog/?p=302).

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about the Mono project? It's an opensource .NET framework that runs cross platform

http://www.mono-project.com/

Comment: Yes I know the project, but that's not the point. And Mono doesn't offer all the features I need on Mac OSX. It is "easier" and more flexible to rewrite the whole project in Java than trying to port the .Net on Mono and have headaches ;-).

Comment: I thought this was a pretty good suggestion considering what you said in your post, although I agree it doesn't directly have to do with your question. No need to be rude to the guy, though.